# Why do I get "undefined method `strip!' for #" when using MiniMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I put the strip method in the CarrierWave initializer:

```
 def strip
   manipulate! do |img|
     img.strip!
     img = yield(img) if block_given?
     img
   end
 end
```

and call on the uploader:

```
 version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fit => [180, nil]
   process :quality => 70
   process :strip   
 end
```

Now Rails spits out this error:

> undefined method `strip!' for #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Undefined #strip Method

You define your method like so:

```
def strip
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.strip!
    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
end
```

but it's unclear from your code sample whether *img* actually has a #strip or #strip! method. The error is complaining about a bang method being undefined, so try `img.strip` instead.

#### Introspection

If that doesn't work, you may want to insert some debugging code in the method so that you can see what *img* really is, and what methods it actually supports. For example:

```
  manipulate! do |img|
    puts img.class
    puts img.methods.sort
    img.strip
    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
```

Hope that helps.

#### See Also

[CarrierWave::MiniMagick](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html)

Comment: <3 the Introspection suggestion. Great general debugging tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

### !

from the strip.